# OneDrive sidebar transition

Tags: css

So recently I found myself racking my brain to find out how OneDrive developers made an incredible transition between li on their sidebar.

I know they use `transition` with `translateY`, but I could not understand how it works, or how `--leftNavIndicatorOffset` is updated, I also wonder if this is purely CSS, but I've been thinking about it for a few days, I tried to figure it out, but I couldn't, so I decided to land here to get some help.

I noticed every `li` has a `::before`, which is the hover border, and only the active `li` has the `::after` border, which is actived by the `navLinkSelected_7c3aa882` class.

I got some code for the page, I'll let it bellow together with a gif, it might be helpful, although you can go to OneDrive page and see yourself for a more realistic experience.

If you can explain how they've done this transition that would be really nice, thank you!

[image]

```css
.groupItems_94cbd27d {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: height var(--durationNormal) var(--curveEasyEaseMax);
}

.navLink_7c3aa882:not(.disabled_7c3aa882):not(.disableIndicator_7c3aa882) {
  position: relative;
}

.navLink_7c3aa882 {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navLink_7c3aa882:not(.disabled_7c3aa882):not( .disableIndicator_7c3aa882).navLinkSelected_7c3aa882::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition-property: var(--leftNavTransitionProperty);
  transform: translateY(var(--leftNavIndicatorOffset));
  transition-duration: var(--durationSlow);
  transition-timing-function: var(--curveDecelerateMax);
  background-color: var(--colorCompoundBrandStroke);
}
```

```html
<div class="navGroup_94cbd27d">
  <div class="groupHeader_94cbd27d">
    <span class="groupName_94cbd27d">João Vitor</span>
  </div>
  <ul role="list" class="groupItems_94cbd27d" aria-label="João Vitor">
    <li role="listitem" class="navLink_7c3aa882">
      <div name="Meus arquivos" class="navLinkInner_7c3aa882" data-actions='[{"key":"nav-link-action","data":"0"}]'>
        <a class="link_7c3aa882" href="#" title="Meus arquivos"><span class="linkFlexContainer_7c3aa882"
            ><span class="linkIconWrapper_7c3aa882"
              ><i
                role="presentation"
                class="icon_52314de0 css-110"
                data-automationid=""
                name="FabricFolder"
              ></i
            ></span>
            <div class="linkTextWrapper_7c3aa882">
              <span class="linkText_7c3aa882">Meus arquivos</span>
            </div></span
          ></a
        >
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="listitem" class="navLink_7c3aa882">
      <div
        name="Recente"
        class="navLinkInner_7c3aa882"
        data-actions='[{"key":"nav-link-action","data":"1"}]'
      >
        <a class="link_7c3aa882" href="#" title="Recente" tabindex="-1"
          ><span class="linkFlexContainer_7c3aa882"
            ><span class="linkIconWrapper_7c3aa882"
              ><i
                role="presentation"
                class="icon_52314de0 css-111"
                data-automationid=""
                name="History"
              ></i
            ></span>
            <div class="linkTextWrapper_7c3aa882">
              <span class="linkText_7c3aa882">Recente</span>
            </div></span
          ></a
        >
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="listitem" class="navLink_7c3aa882">
      <div
        name="Fotos"
        class="navLinkInner_7c3aa882"
        data-actions='[{"key":"nav-link-action","data":"8"}]'
      >
        <a class="link_7c3aa882" href="#" title="Fotos" tabindex="-1"
          ><span class="linkFlexContainer_7c3aa882"
            ><span class="linkIconWrapper_7c3aa882"
              ><i
                role="presentation"
                class="icon_52314de0 css-218"
                data-automationid=""
                name="Photo"
              ></i
            ></span>
            <div class="linkTextWrapper_7c3aa882">
              <span class="linkText_7c3aa882">Fotos</span>
            </div></span
          ></a
        >
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="listitem" class="navLink_7c3aa882">
      <div
        name="Compartilhado"
        class="navLinkInner_7c3aa882"
        data-actions='[{"key":"nav-link-action","data":"3"}]'
      >
        <a class="link_7c3aa882" href="#" title="Compartilhado" tabindex="-1"
          ><span class="linkFlexContainer_7c3aa882"
            ><span class="linkIconWrapper_7c3aa882"
              ><i
                role="presentation"
                class="icon_52314de0 css-112"
                data-automationid=""
                name="People"
              ></i
            ></span>
            <div class="linkTextWrapper_7c3aa882">
              <span class="linkText_7c3aa882">Compartilhado</span>
            </div></span
          ></a
        >
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="listitem" class="navLink_7c3aa882 navLinkSelected_7c3aa882">
      <div
        name="Lixeira"
        class="navLinkInner_7c3aa882"
        data-actions='[{"key":"nav-link-action","data":"5"}]'
      >
        <a
          class="link_7c3aa882"
          href="#"
          title="Lixeira"
          tabindex="-1"
          aria-current="page"
          ><span class="linkFlexContainer_7c3aa882"
            ><span class="linkIconWrapper_7c3aa882"
              ><i
                role="presentation"
                class="icon_52314de0 css-113"
                data-automationid=""
                name="RecycleBin"
              ></i
            ></span>
            <div class="linkTextWrapper_7c3aa882">
              <span class="linkText_7c3aa882">Lixeira</span>
            </div></span
          ></a
        >
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, the HTML+CSS in your post doesn't reproduce the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this kind of code should do it;

```css
.container {
  width      : 220px; 
  background : whitesmoke;
  --hg-Dim   : 20px;
  height     : calc( 7 * var(--hg-Dim) );
  overflow   : hidden;
  }
.container div {
  margin:  0;
  height: var(--hg-Dim);
  }
.row-text {
  width  : 200px;
  float  : right;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
.row-mask {
  width      : 15px;
  transition : height 300ms linear;
  }
.mark {
  width      : 10px;
  background : red;
  display    : none;
  }
.row-text:focus {
  background : aquamarine;
  }
.row-text:focus ~ .row-mask { 
  height : 0;
  }
.row-text:focus ~ .mark { 
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 1 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 2 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 3 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 4 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 5 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 6 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="row-text" tabindex="1"> menu element 7 </div><div class="row-mask"></div>
  <div class="mark"> </div>
</div>
```

I leave the management of transitions to you